# how to install pkg-config, sigc++-2.0 with vcpkg on windows 10

Tags: pkg-config, vcpkg

I want to build vs 2017 project files on windows 10 with vcpkg, cmake and pkg-config.

and Now I installed vcpkg successfully, and checked there were 26 *.pc files in C:\src\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows\lib\pkgconfig directory.

When I search string like *sigc* with vcpkg, found a libsigcpp which is already installed.
I need sigc++-2.0 to be found by pkg-config, how?